# Why am I receiving a fileNotFoundException error on my code?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Here is the code:

I am new to java and stackoverflow so please excuse any mistakes.

```
public class Actions {
    
    private static String datesFileName = "./Dates.txt";
    
    private static String actionsFileName = "./Actions.txt";
    
    private static File datesFile = new File(datesFileName);
    
    private static File actionsFile =  new File(actionsFileName);
    
    
    private static ArrayList<String[]> actions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private static ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Actions() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        
        txtToDates();
        
        txtToActions();
        
    }

    public static void txtToActions() throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        Scanner tempSc = new Scanner(actionsFile);
        
        int counter = 0;
        
        while(tempSc.hasNextLine()) {
            actions.add(new String[24]);
            for(int innerCounter=0; innerCounter<24; innerCounter++) {
                actions.get(counter)[innerCounter] = tempSc.next();
            }
            counter++;
        }
        tempSc.close();
    }
```

}

When i attempt to create an instance of said class in another class, i get a file not found exception. Why is that? Where is the error in the constructor and how can it be fixed?
I am lost since I had similar methods with a similar class and it ran just fine.

Comment: Is there a copy&paste error in your code? Actions appears 2 times

Comment: Yes, fixed it just now

Comment: "Where is the error" - have you tried to check whether the file exists? What else have you tried to debug the problem?